# Error encoding arguments: Error: types/values length mismatch

Tags: solidity

Can't seem to understand the reason of this error. I have the following structs:

```
enum RecordType {ONE, TWO, THREE}

struct Record {
        address recordmaker;
        uint256[] recordIds;
        RecordType recordType;
    }

struct Book {
        Record[] records;
        address bookmaker;
        uint256 salt;
    }
```

There's a `Book` struct that can hold several `Record` structs, basically. Now, I need to create hash a new `Book`, and for that I'm using the following code:

```
bytes32 constant BOOK_TYPEHASH = keccak256(
        "Book(Record[] records,address bookmaker,uint256 salt)"
    );

function hashBook(Book calldata book) external pure returns (bytes32) {
    return keccak256(abi.encode(
        BOOK_TYPEHASH,
        book.records,
        book.bookmaker,
        book.salt
    ));
}
```

To test the hashing, I pass the following to the function:

```
([0xD7ACd2a9FD159E69Bb102A1ca21C9a3e3A5F771B, [5, 55, 125], 0], 0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138, 123456)
```

Or the preview:

```
    (
        [
            0xD7ACd2a9FD159E69Bb102A1ca21C9a3e3A5F771B, 
            [
                5, 
                55, 
                125
            ],
            0
        ], 
        0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138, 
        123456
    )
```

When invoking the function, I get: `transact to BookContract.hashBook errored. Error encoding arguments: Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":1,"values":3}, value={"types":["tuple(tuple(address,uint256[],uint8)[],address,uint256)"],"values":["([0xD7ACd2a9FD159E69Bb102A1ca21C9a3e3A5F771B, [5,",", 125], 0],",", 123456)"]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.0.7)`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few syntax errors in your expression. You should:

- Use square brackets `[` instead of regular brackets `(` for wrapping a struct
- Wrap the `Record` struct in square brackets `[` as well
- Wrap the addresses in quotes `"`

```
[[["0xD7ACd2a9FD159E69Bb102A1ca21C9a3e3A5F771B", [5, 55, 125], 0]], "0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138", 123456]
```

Preview:

```
[  // start of `Book` struct
    [  // start of `records[]` array
        [  // start of `Record` struct
            "0xD7ACd2a9FD159E69Bb102A1ca21C9a3e3A5F771B",
            [
                5,
                55,
                125
            ],
            0
        ]
    ],
    "0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138",
    123456
]
```